# Unable to access SharedPreferences value from a class into an activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am working on a server baser application so whenever a user logs in i have to capture his unique userId and use it in different activities in my whole project.
So after getting the userId from JSONObject i am putting it in sharedPrederence and getting it in another activity but after entering into my main activity which is after successful login the shared preference shows me the default value of userId which is zero.

**Here is my code in PostData.java class which will work in background of login activity:**

```
private SharedPreferences userIdSharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor userIdEditor;

              try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                    //boolean requestStatus = obj.getBoolean("requestStatus");
                    JSONObject data = obj.getJSONObject("data"); 
                    userId = Integer.parseInt(data.getString("userId"));            
                    userIdEditor = userIdSharedPreferences.edit();
                    userIdEditor.putInt("crrUserId", userId);
                    userIdEditor.apply();
                    userIdEditor.commit();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

**and here is how i am using that sharedPreference value in other acitivity:**

```
userIdSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    crrUserId = userIdSharedPreferences.getInt("crrUserId", 0);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your user id is: " + crrUserId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //This toast showing 0 which is default i set.
```

**EDIT**

for more clarification now i am passing my userId from my background class PostData.java to my LoginActivity using the below function:

```
    Integer passUserId() {
    return userId;
}
```

and from there i am passing userId using sharedPreference like this:

```
Intent loginSuccess = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            Integer crrUserId = Login.passUserId(); //Login is name of variable which will accespassUserId function in PostData.java class
            SharedPreferences userIdSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("userId", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor userIdEditor;
            userIdEditor = userIdSharedPreferences.edit();
            userIdEditor.putInt("crrUserId", crrUserId);
            userIdEditor.apply();
            startActivity(loginSuccess);
            finish();
```

and here is how i am using in my mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SharedPreferences userIdSharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor userIdEditor;
Integer crrUserId;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    userIdSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    crrUserId = userIdSharedPreferences.getInt("userId", 0);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your user id is: " + crrUserId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}

Comment: and how do you init `userIdSharedPreferences`in your PostData.java?

Comment: have you initialiased userIdSharedPreferences in PostData.java before saving userid?

Comment: show your userIdSharedPreferences definition in your code.

Comment: check if your key is exist in the SharedPreference sharedPrefs.contains("crrUserId") if not then there might be initialization issue.

Comment: yes @e-LogicSense
and code updated you can see definition now

Comment: You have declared the variable, but not defined it. In your try{} block, define the userIdSharedPreferences and userIdEditor before using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

First you need to initialize `userIdSharedPreferences` object like below:

```
userIdSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

After getting object of `SharedPreference` do this:

```
userIdEditor = userIdSharedPreferences.edit();
```

After getting object of `SharedPreferences.Editor` do your task.

Comment: It says this: `'getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)' in 'android.preference.PreferenceManager' cannot be applied to '(com.scoratech.studentapp.LoginActivity.ValidateUserAccount)'` as i am defining sharedPreference in Async task function.

Comment: yes, can i define and put userId value to sharedPreference out of aSync function?

Comment: You must define global context object for this.

Comment: Nivesh Shastri can you  please help me with that? it will be great progress into my project.

Comment: @Khan replace 'this' to 'LoginActivity.this'

Comment: @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            userId = Login.passUserId();
            if (code == 200) {
                userIdSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
                Intent loginSuccess = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                userIdEditor = userIdSharedPreferences.edit();
                userIdEditor.putInt("userId", userId);
                userIdEditor.apply();
                startActivity(loginSuccess);
        }

Answer (score 1):

> initialiase userIdSharedPreferences may be thats the problem

```html
   try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            //boolean requestStatus = obj.getBoolean("requestStatus");
            JSONObject data = obj.getJSONObject("data");
            userId = Integer.parseInt(data.getString("userId"));

            SharedPreferences userIdSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);

            SharedPreferences.Editor userIdEditor = userIdSharedPreferences.edit();
            userIdEditor.putInt("crrUserId", userId);
            userIdEditor.apply(); //apply or commit not both
            userIdEditor.commit();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Hey, getApplicationContext() wont work because this class has no activity.

Comment: you can init preference outside of response also.init in oncreate of class

Comment: I have updated the code which will give you more clear idea please read it once again.